# Draw Line With Starting Circle

Tags: android, android-drawable, layer-list

I am Using Drawable For Draw Horizontal Line With Starting Small Circle In android But The Circle Comes With Center Of the Horizontal Line.
    This is my code. 
    android->res->drawable Folder.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:gravity="start">

        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="6dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>

    </item>

    <item >
        <shape
            android:shape="line">
            <size
                android:width="200dp"
                android:height="200dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#0000FF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
```

Please Help me to solve this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item >
        <shape
            android:shape="line">
            <size
                android:width="200dp"
                android:height="200dp" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#0000FF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:gravity="start" android:left="-188dp">

        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="6dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Also, to place this drawable in imageview then follow this code.

```
<ImageView
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/test"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp" />
```

Comment: tq for your help bro

Comment: I am Set This Drawable to Imageview Width MatchParent I Cannot Perfectly Set Circle Little Move From Start To Right I dont konw Why?

Comment: @karthik , add your `ImageView ` code with your question.

Comment: <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/line_with_dot">
    </ImageView>

Comment: Check the answer again.

Comment: tq but but line match parent is not possible? why? bro

Comment: Not possible by this way. You have to use 9-patch image for that. More details follow this link. https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch

Comment: tq for your cooperation bro